# Angular app with typescript build error on Azure DevOps pipeline - error TS2677

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, lodash

The following error is happening only during **Npm@1** task on the DevOps pipeline. The app builds just fine locally. No errors at all.

Angular CLI version is 8.3.29 and TypeScript version is 3.5.3.

It's executing this custom command:

```
run build:artifact
```

and that custom command points to this in `package.json`:

```
ng build --configuration=artifact
```

The error being thrown is:

> ../node_modules/@types/lodash/common/lang.d.ts:577:74 - error TS2677:
> A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.

Full log from the pipeline:

```
Starting: Angular Build
==============================================================================
Task         : npm
Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Azure Artifacts.
Version      : 1.202.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.15.0\x64\npm.cmd --version"
6.14.8
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.15.0\x64\npm.cmd config list"
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.14.8 node/v14.15.0 win32 x64"

; environment configs
prefix = "C:\\npm\\prefix"
userconfig = "D:\\a\\1\\npm\\11507.npmrc"

; globalconfig C:\npm\prefix\etc\npmrc
cache = "C:\\npm\\cache"

; node bin location = C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.15.0\x64\node.exe
; cwd = D:\a\1\s\client-site-spa
; HOME = C:\Users\VssAdministrator
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\14.15.0\x64\npm.cmd run build:artifact"

ERROR in ../node_modules/@types/lodash/common/lang.d.ts:577:74 - error TS2677: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'EmptyObjectOf<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'EmptyObjectOf<T>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'.
      Type 'EmptyObject<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'EmptyObject<T>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'.

577         isEmpty<T extends object>(value: T | null | undefined): value is EmptyObjectOf<T> | null | undefined;
                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project-angular@0.0.0 build:artifact: `ng build --configuration=artifact`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the project-angular@0.0.0 build:artifact script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-08-17T15_41_17_869Z-debug.log

> project-angular@0.0.0 build:artifact D:\a\1\s\client-site-spa
> ng build --configuration=artifact
```

Do you know how to hunt down where this error is being thrown?

When I run the same command [ `ng build --configuration=artifact` ] manually on my dev box with matching node\npm versions, no error happens:

[image]

#######

After deleting the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file as MikeOne suggested, I was able to get the same error from the pipeline locally... however it still doesn't tell us in what file the error is happening. :|

[image: package-lock]

#######

There's no indication this error is happening anywhere on my own source code. Would this be an error from `lodash` itself? I'm using the latest version available as of now [4.17.21](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash).

[image]

#######

This seems to be the interface member that the TypeScript compiler is barking about... however, I'm not calling it anywhere on my code.

[image]

Comment: What happens when locally you delete package_lock and node_modules and do an npm i? Do you then also get the error locally?

Comment: It's a day old commit: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/3ea5c2f388bbc2cd0a105dde53b391f82158eb64 which broke the package. It'll be fine if you keep `@types/lodash` one version earlier, e.g. `4.14.182`. Or you can track the issue on their Github: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/61772

Comment: @skink you nailed it! You can add it as an answer. I'll mark it as accepted. :) ha... I bumped lodash types yesterday to match the project's TypeScript version. It was way behind... now it all makes sense!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[A recent commit](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/3ea5c2f388bbc2cd0a105dde53b391f82158eb64) has broken the package. The issue is being tracked on [their Github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/61772), but in the meantime we could stick to the previous version of `@types/lodash` which is `4.14.182`.

Comment: If we are using `types/lodash-es`, what version of that should we use? Tried using older versions but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @Yahya Uddin I don't think such a version exists, but adding "@types/lodash": "4.14.182" along side of it will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error when I was updating the npm-check version from 5.9.0 to  6.0.1

If you notice the error:

`/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/lang.d.ts:577:74`

it occurs because of @types/lodash package. You can always check the tree structure of the package by following command:

`npm list <package-name>`
`npm list @types/lodash`

I got following output:

└─┬ npm-check@6.0.1
└─┬ callsite-record@4.1.4
└── @types/lodash@4.14.185

so it clearly tells, it happens because of npm-check version update.